# Adjusting two adjacent box sizers to fit into wxDialog

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

WxDialog box has more sizers in which two box sizers are adjacent to each other.
These sizers has more controls like ListCtrl,StatisTextCtlr,TreeCtrl etc.

The content of length of any one sizers is too long dialog box increasing horizontally,So that both sizers increased.

So,can we give horizontal scrollbar(dynamically) to the 1st sizer when 2nd sizers content length increased?.So that we can prevent the dialog box from horizontally increasing size.

```
def __init__(self, parent, Name, Platform, someList=None):

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, 'select name', size=(-1,-1), pos=(-1,-1))

    # Generate UI
        self.createLayout()
        self.createSizers()


        self.Fit()
        self.Layout()
        self.CenterOnParent()

 def createSizers(self):

    self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    ..............

    SelectionSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.staticBoxSelection, wx.VERTICAL)
        self.horzDetailsSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    self.userDetailsSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.userDetailsSizer.Add(self.DetailsName, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT)

    self.userListingSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.userListingSizer.Add(self.LocationSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.userListingSizer.AddSpacer(5)
        self.userListingSizer.Add(self.ListBox, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        # Horizontal Splitter
        self.horzDetailsSizer.Add(self.userListingSizer, 3, wx.EXPAND)
        self.horzDetailsSizer.AddSpacer(5)
        self.horzDetailsSizer.Add(self.userDetailsSizer, 2, wx.EXPAND)

        # Add selection subsizers to main
        SelectionSizer.Add(self.horzDetailsSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        ............

    self.mainSizer.AddSpacer(5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.headerText, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        self.mainSizer.AddSpacer(8)
        self.mainSizer.Add(mainHeader, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 35)
        self.mainSizer.AddSpacer(5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(SelectionSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        self.mainSizer.AddSpacer(5)
    .............
    ....... 

    ## Initialize mainSize
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
```

Thanks in Advance.Any answers would be appreciated

Comment: use panels and then put you sizers on them. Sizers are not windows and therefore can't have an additional children. Panels are.

Comment: Can I create panels without modifying anything here?.please give some sample.it would be helpful for me.I am very new to wxpython

Comment: My guess is instead of `size=(-1,-1)` if we give manual size for dialog like `size=(850,700)` the sizers will scroll to fit the window.But this is even not increasing the window size.I dont know why?,,Do you have any idea?